# amsthm and amssymb disappeared after updating?

Tags: miktex, amsthm, amssymb

I had recently updated my MikTeX 2.9, but after I did that, two packages - `amsthm` and `amssymb` - disappeared. My editor outputs an error whenever I call them, and I can't find them in the package manager. Any idea on how this happened? Can I download `amsthm.sty` and `amssymb.sty` from anywhere else?

EDIT: It turns out that `amsthm` and `amssymb` are part of the `amscls` package - so installing that package off of the package manager did the trick.

Comment: You can download the missing packages manually from [http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) and [http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb](http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb).

Comment: Synchronize the repository in the package manager and then reinstall the packages. And don't update currently miktex-runtime-bin: There seems to be a bug.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Also, the article on http://latex-community.org/home/news/46-news-latex-distributions/469-miktex-amsmath deals with the problem.

Comment: i have added a note to my answer to the question cited by @egreg, explaining the circumstances.