# dvips has problems finding a font

Tags: miktex, dvips

The following mystery/error baffles me.

OS: Windows 7

SW: MikTeX 2.9.3888, WinEdt 7.0

Problem: While running `divps`, the following messages appear in the console

```
Trying to make PK font ecbx1200 at 600 DPI...
The PK font file `C:\Users\Jyrki\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/dpi600\ecbx1200.pk` already exists.
```

... and a couple of lines further down:

```
`dvips.exe`: Font ecbx1200 not found; characters will be left blank.
```

This is all Greek to me, but may be somebody can suggest a fix? I don't know where this font is used, but I would guess that it is the bold text in **Theorem**, **Lemma** and such. The symptoms of this are even more baffling, because a document with the following header source

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,leqno]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym,epsf,amsthm}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}  %for thesis
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}   %for thesis
\setlength{\baselineskip}{18pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.9in}
\global\baselineskip=18pt

\newtheorem{lause}{Lause}
\newtheorem{lemma}[lause]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{seuraus}[lause]{Seuraus}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{huomautus}[lause]{Huomautus}
\newtheorem{esimerkki}[lause]{Esimerkki}
\newtheorem{maaritelma}[lause]{Määritelmä}
\newtheorem{exer}{Harjoitustehtävä}
\newenvironment{todistus}{{\noindent \bf Todistus.}\rm}{\qed\medskip}
\newenvironment{ratkaisu}{{\noindent \bf Ratkaisu.}\rm}{\medskip}
```

results in a document that

1. `divpdf` refuses to proceed with (citing missing font `ecbx1200`)
2. processing via `divps` and `ps2pdf` gives a document, where the theorem headers (and numbers) are missing
3. was processed correctly on my previous laptop (older versions of both MikTeX and WinEdt running on WinXP)

**BUT** another document with IMHO essential identical header source

```
\documentclass{report}[12pt]

\usepackage{latexsym,epsf,amsthm}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}  %for thesis
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}   %for thesis
\setlength{\baselineskip}{18pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.9in}
\global\baselineskip=18pt

\newtheorem{lause}{Lause}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[lause]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{seuraus}[lause]{Seuraus}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{huomautus}[lause]{Huomautus}
\newtheorem{esimerkki}[lause]{Esimerkki}
\newtheorem{maaritelma}[lause]{Määritelmä}
\newenvironment{todistus}{{\noindent \bf Todistus.}\rm}{\qed\medskip}
\newenvironment{ratkaisu}{{\noindent \bf Ratkaisu.}\rm}{\medskip}
```

gives

1. the same error messages
2. but no characters are missing from the output after the `dvips` + `ps2pdf` route.

Conceivably, `amsmath` could use a different font here for `article`s and `report`s. That might explain the difference in behavior, but I'm more interested in getting a fix.

Comment: My first question here. Sorry if off-topic, or if I've done something non-kosher. Should have lurked for a while, but urgency got to me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Thanks Peter, should have figured that out on my own, but this was probably faster :-)

Comment: The easiest fix is to add `\usepackage{lmodern}`

Comment: @egreg I guess it's a font encoding error? Computer Modern (the default) requires OT1 as its encoding, right?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen you have `ä` in your file without using `inputenc.sty`. This is a recipe for (mild) disaster when using "vanilla" latex or pdflatex.

Comment: @kahen: Thanks for the tip. The scandic letters "äöåÄÖÅ" are, indeed, occasionally a problem (in particular when exchanging TeX-sources with fellow countrymen using a different platform), but one of the packages (fontenc ?) does take care of that. I can't do without as those letters. They, at least "äöÄÖ", are very common in my native language.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen with your permission if you found a duplicate, should this Q be close as duplicate of Q mentioned in your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, dear. A little bit of further digging would have helped.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98062/9446) seems definitely related. That question is itself a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96778/9446). The suggested remedy listing the packages that I need to upload seems to have fixed my problem.

This was not the best start for my stay in TeX.SE. Sorry about that. If somebody wants to add something, please do so, and I will upvote and accept. Otherwise I will just wrap this up the best I can. May be this should be closed as a duplicate?

Apparently I'm out of practice in solving SW-problems (and whatever experience I have at that is from the DOS-era anyway, so...)

Comment: The correlation isn't too obvious between the two, so maybe rework this into an explanation of how the solution to that one leads to a solution for this one.  (And don't worry -- if you find one person on this site who has *never* jumped the gun, I'd be astonished; especially when it's urgent and panicky ;))